# Is my drive failing and is this the same reason my laptop is running slower?

Tags: hard-disk, performance, disk, storage

I run Ubuntu-20 and I have scanned my laptop using [smartctl](https://www.smartmontools.org/). The test results are as follows:

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 32
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       807002
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0023   100   100   002    Pre-fail  Always       -       1261
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4358
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   001   001   005    Pre-fail  Always   FAILING_NOW 9800
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002f   100   100   070    Pre-fail  Always       -       17337
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       6550
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2741
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       85
184 End-to-End_Error        0x003b   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       96
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       290
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       1274
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       347892351057
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   084   084   000    Old_age   Always       -       32166
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   032   050   000    Old_age   Always       -       32 (Min/Max 23/32)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0


SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed: unknown failure    90%      6523         0
# 2  Short offline       Completed: unknown failure    90%      6511         0
# 3  Extended offline    Completed: unknown failure    90%      6511         0
# 4  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      6507         1632567256
# 5  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      6497         1284529824
# 6  Short offline       Completed: read failure       10%      6495         1528570456
# 7  Short offline       Completed: read failure       10%      6495         1280234720
# 8  Short offline       Completed: read failure       10%      6495         1288689848
# 9  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      6492         1235843824
#10  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3452         -
#11  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1539         -
#12  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1230         -
```

Is my drive failing?
I am observing a lag in the system. It takes lot of time to read and write files. Also, my filesystem sometimes go read-only (shows read-only filesystem, unable to perform operations).

I have good amount of resourses (12GB RAM and i3 7th gen).

What steps should I take to recover these things?

Comment: Is there anything regarding your drive in the system logs (e.g. `/var/log/syslog`)? Especially when the file system goes read-only?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, your drive is failing:

```
 5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   001   001   005    Pre-fail  Always   FAILING_NOW 9800
```

There’s nothing you can do to make the drive “better”. What you need to do next depends on what backups you have, if any. If you don’t have any, stop using your system and get an external drive at least as large as your laptop’s drive, and then copy as much of your laptop’s drive to it as possible (using `ddrescue`).

Comment: [Highest voted Answers containing "ddrescue" - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=ddrescue%20is%3aA)

Comment: The reallocated sectors are also responsible for the lag: with almost 10000 of them, the drive will frequently need to interrupt a fast sequential read to perform a pair of slow seeks to read the reallocated sector.